# How to prove R is a local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If Jacobson radical is a prime ideal and R is semi local then how to prove R is a local ring?

Suppose R has two maximal ideals M and N. Let x belongs to M-N and y belongs to N- M, then xy belongs to J(R). Since J(R) is prime, we have either x or y belongs to J(R). If x belongs to J(R) then x belongs to N. Similarly if y belongs to J(R). This is a contradiction.
Is this is enough to prove the result

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: Thank you for improving the context!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. $xy$ is in $M\cap N$ of course, but how do you know it's in $J(R)$? It could be that $xy\in (M\cap N)\setminus J(R)$.

Another red flag is that you didn't use the semilocal hypothesis.  That does not mean you are wrong in itself, but it does draw ones attention to potential counterexamples. If your reasoning were valid, and since it makes no use of the semilocal hypothesis, we'd be able to apply your argument to $\mathbb Z$ to claim it is local!  Of course this is not the case...

But you are not too far off.  Since $R$ is semilocal, it has only finitely many maximal ideals $M_j$.  You can indeed demonstrate there is a set of elements $x_i$ such that $x_i\in M_i$ but $x_i\notin M_j$ for some $j\neq i$. The product $x=\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\in J(R)$ **because $\prod_{i=1}^n M_i\subseteq\bigcap_{i=1}^n M_i=J(R)$**.  (Two ideals might not have been enough.) Now try what you were trying before again with this new $x$.

Comment: From context I infer you are talking about a commutative ring.